# Binding Eclipse Library Project with Xamarin: At least one Java library is required for binding, this must be either 'EmbeddedJar'...for build action

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We need to bind the Pulltoloadmoreandrefresh Eclipse Library Project in our Xamarin Android project as mentioned in [Binding an Eclipse Library Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-library-project/).

1. We created the Eclipse library project, added the respective files [(screenshot for reference)](https://1drv.ms/i/s!ArmvMJfDes95iD4pqHR1h7CWsP53),  and created the zip files with res and bin folders as mentioned in the above link.
2. Created the Android Library Project in Visual Studio and added the the zip file. But it shows error `"At least one Java library is required for binding, this must be either 'EmbeddedJar', 'InputJar' (for jar), 'LibraryProjectZip' (for aar or zip) or 'LibraryProjectProperties' (project.properties) build action" for build action "LibraryProjectZip"`

Kindly suggest on how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you set the build action in the properties of the included project zip file?

Comment: Yes , i have set the build action as "LibraryProjectZip"for the zip file.

Comment: Guys, Any solution you found out for this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by swapping in [Build Action](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/#Build_Actions).

For me the solution came with the type *InputJar* in the project that generates the library for Xamarin.

[image: My Setup was as follows]

[image: And this was the end result]